# Laravel: Action App\Http\Controllers\NotesController@store not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have a form

```
<form action="{{ action('NotesController@store') }}" method="post">
    //
</form>
```

The action points to the `store` method in the NotesController controller in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory.

The `NotesController` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NotesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // var_dump($request);
        //
        // $note = new Note();


    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But when I try to render the page that displays my form (so before even submitting it, just trying to render the form itself) I get the following error:

> Action App\Http\Controllers\NotesController@store not defined. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\personal_projects\Active\diary_app\resources\views\diary\entry.blade.php)

Comment: Have you added routes in the file ?

Comment: Add your route for `NotesController@store` in question!

Comment: Which Laravel version is it?

Comment: It's 5.5, I have added `Route::resource('notes', 'NotesController');` and it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to define web routes for the controller in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::resource('notes', 'NotesController');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `action()` helper to generate an URL to your route:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action('NotesController@store') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

You can also use like:

**In Route:**

```
Route::post('notes', 
      array('uses'=>'App\Controllers\NotesController@store',
             'as' => 'notes.create'));
```

**In View:**

`{{ Form::open(array('url'=>route('notes.create'))) }}`

And if you are using Laravel resourceController, then use:

```
Route::resource('notes', 'NotesController');
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and see what you get:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('create', 'NotesController@Create');
Route::post('create', 'NotesController@Store');
```

form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/create">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{-- START - FORM DATA --}}
    
    {{-- END - FORM DATA --}}
</form>
```